# How to write a function that updates materialized views with dependencies on each other

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I want to write a query that will update all materialized views in the database. The materialized views have dependencies on each other so they have to be materialized in a certain order.

Is there a way to come up with a query that will do this in a hands off way? Meaning I don't have to maintain some data structure that records the dependencies. Just every-time I add a new materialized view it will be updated in the right order. This could be an internal sql routine or an external app that calls the query periodically.

I was thinking of using row creation time of pg_matview but postgresql doesn't record this anywhere.